# Scaling canvas on Firefox doesn't effect SVG images

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, html5-canvas

Firefox does not respect 2D canvas transformation for SVG images, however, it does for PNG pictures.

The following code snippet creates two HTML canvases with 2D drawing contexts. On both of them a simple scale transformation is applied, then a 20px sized square PNG image is drawn on the upper one, and an SVG with the same dimensions is drawn on the bottom one.

On my Chromium (v65.0.3325.162) the images are scaled up as expected. However, on Firefox (v58.0.2) the canvas at the bottom (the one with the SVG) is not scaled, unlike the one with PNG source image.

```js
function createPng(xSize, ySize) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 20;
  canvas.height = 20;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  ctx.fillStyle = "000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, xSize, ySize);
  
  var img = new Image()
  prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    img.onload = function() {resolve(img)}
    img.onerror = function(err) {reject(err)}
  })
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return prom
}

function createSvg() {
  var img = new Image()
  var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    img.onload = function() {resolve(img)}
    img.onerror = function(err) {reject(err)}
  })
  img.src =  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/AttilaVM/4e0987aae8bc37b2067fbde591088758/raw/95dcffd67b37540d739f4bd5f33f6bead625a90f/test.svg"
  return prom
}

var containerPng = document.getElementById("container-png")
var canvasPng = document.createElement("canvas")

canvasPng.width = containerPng.clientWidth;
canvasPng.height = containerPng.clientHeight;

containerPng.appendChild(canvasPng);

var ctxPng = canvasPng.getContext("2d");

createPng(20, 20)
.then(function(img) {
  ctxPng.scale(5, 1); 
  ctxPng.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
})
.catch(function(err) {console.error(err)});

var containerSvg = document.getElementById("container-svg")
var canvasSvg = document.createElement("canvas")

canvasSvg.width = containerSvg.clientWidth;
canvasSvg.height = containerSvg.clientHeight;

containerSvg.appendChild(canvasSvg);
var ctxSvg = canvasSvg.getContext("2d");

createSvg()
.then(function(img) {
  ctxSvg.scale(5, 1); 
  ctxSvg.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
})
.catch(function(err) {console.error(err)});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa
}

.container > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-png" class="container"></div>
<div id="container-svg" class="container"></div>
```

#### Screenshots

Chromium:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

#### Question:

What is the best way to write code to draw scaled SVG images on HTML canvas, which gives the same result on both Firefox and Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in fact a bug. In your original svg, the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute is missing. This means that the default value is used which is `XMidYMid`. That will create the problem if the `viewBox` **aspect ratio** of the svg does not match to the aspect ratio of the target **viewPort** (you image). To turn this off, you need to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your svg. I went to the source of the svg, added the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute and then did this:

```
var x = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+ btoa(ser.serializeToString(document.querySelector("svg")))
```

The `ser` above is an XMLSerializer instance. This will give me a data url which I can use:

```
"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxuczpvc2I9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cub3BlbnN3YXRjaGJvb2sub3JnL3VyaS8yMDA5L29zYiIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI2LjQ1OCAyNi40NTgiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIHdpZHRoPSIyMCIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IG9zYjpwYWludD0iZ3JhZGllbnQiIGlkPSJhIj48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjAiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlMjVlNWUiLz48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMxMjkwMzMiLz48L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCB5Mj0iMjk1LjQ4MiIgeDI9IjEyLjYxNCIgeTE9IjI3Mi4xNjQiIHgxPSIxMi4xOSIgZ3JhZGllbnRUcmFuc2Zvcm09Im1hdHJpeCgxLjExMzQ3IDAgMCAxLjExMzQ3IC0xLjUwMSAtMzIuMTk4KSIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIGlkPSJiIiB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjYSIvPjwvZGVmcz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2IpIiBkPSJNMCAyNzAuNTQyaDI2LjQ1OFYyOTdIMHoiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgLTI3MC41NDIpIi8+PC9zdmc+"
```

Next , I created a fiddle and modified these:

```
function createSvg() {
  var img = new Image()
  var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    img.onload = function() {resolve(img)}
    img.onerror = function(err) {reject(err)}
  })
  img.src =  "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
  return prom
}
```

See the fiddle here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ibowankenobi/4ntq2qLz/1/

Seems like it solved the problem in the firefox browser I was testing.

Comment: Thank you. I applied your advice on my original code and now it works on Firefox too.